# Azure AD Automatic User Provisioning With App registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm new to Azure AD and I'm trying to create an app (that I'm developing) and setup an automated user provisioning (SCIM).

The first thing I need to do is to create an application, so I go the **App registration** in the Azure AD portal and create one. It's a multi-tent application.

After that I navigated to the **Authentication** menu and added a *Mobile and Desktop configuration only*. A Service principal is automatically created in the **Enterprise applications** menu.

When I go the **Provisioning** menu that is supposed to allow me to configure the automated user provisioning I get this:

**"Out of the box automatic provisioning to AppName is not supported today. Ensure that AppName supports the SCIM standard for provisioning and request support for the application as described here. To determine if the application suports SCIM, please contact the application developer."**

Does anyone knows why this is happening? Is it because I've added only a **Desktop and Mobile platform configuration**? I can't find any good explanation and I can't figure out how to make it work and what I'm supposed to do to make it work.

How am i supposed to make the automatic user provisioning work on my own application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provisioning is a feature for Enterprise Applications, which are slightly different in nature from (and have some overlap with) App Registrations. Create an Enterprise Application - a custom/non-gallery app is fine - and you'll be able to enable provisioning on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If my application is available in the gallery later on and other people add it to their Active Directory as an Enterprise application, will they be able to setup the automatic user provisioning then?

Comment: If you're using a custom non-gallery app/app registration in your own tenant, that's really just for your own use. You can submit a request to publish an Enterprise Application into the Azure AD gallery via this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing

You'll then work with different teams to handle both the SSO(SAML or OIDC) and/or Provisioning (SCIM 2.0) integration configuration for the app that shows in the gallery.